# A linear functional of $H^k$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Define $H^k$ as usual: $$H^k=\left\{f; \int (1+|\xi|^2)^k|\widehat{f}(\xi)|^2d\xi<\infty\right\}$$
Define $l(u)=\int (1+|\xi|^2)^k\widehat{u}(\xi)d\xi$, how to show that $l\in (H^k)^*$. I tried showing $l\in H^{-k}$ but the computation is ugly. Is there a neater way to do it? Any hints/ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure $l$ is as written? Take $\hat{u}(\xi)=(1+|\xi|^2)^{r/2}$ with $r=-(2/3)(n+2k)$. Then $u\in H^k$ but $l(u)=\infty$.